# Highlight all dates from now until 2 weeks later

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a script where i have a table that contains dates for supplies. Now there are alot of dates +- 600. Now what i want to do is to highligt all dates that will expire from today untill two weeks later or if the date is allready in the past. 
the table looks like this

now these are just a few lines. But how can I highlight all dates from today untill two weeks later and dates in the past automatticly...
i have allready searched alot, and the only thing i can find is to highligt between 2 dates, but i want that to be automaticly--> date today - 2 weeks later (and this updates avery day automatticly)

srry for my english, i hope the question is clear
thx in advance

updated code:

```
<?php 
// get two weeks from now
$date_in_two_weeks = strtotime('+2 weeks');
$date_in_two_weeks = date("Y-m-d",$date_in_two_weeks);

// get the date to compare, from db or whatever you want
$date_to_compare = "2014-02-01";

// compare the date in your list to now + 2 weeks and then put the date difference into $days_difference
$date_from_list = new DateTime($date_to_compare);
$date_in_two_weeks = new DateTime($date_in_two_weeks);
$days_difference = $date_from_list->diff($date_in_two_weeks);

if ($days_difference->days > 14) {
    $highlight_css_class = "highlight";
} else {
    $highlight_css_class = "none";
}
?>
<style>
.highlight { 
    color:#cc0000;
}
.none { 
}
</style>
<fieldset>
<table class="tablesorter" id="my-table" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>REK</th>
                <th>BESCHRIJVING</th>
                <th>VERVALDATUM</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


<tr><td>A1</td><td>hamburger</td><td class="<?php echo $highlight_css_class;?>">2014-02-10</td></tr>

<tr><td>A1</td><td>tomato</td><td class="<?php echo $highlight_css_class;?>">2014-06-10</td></tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

so all dates have the class highlight now and they are all red...?
what am i doing wrong with this code?
i dont understand

Comment: how do you display the table, show some code for the current table?

Comment: the table is displayed like that, except the date is a variable like $tomato =  "2014-01-09";

Comment: you could get 2 weeks advance by `strtotime('+2 weeks')`

Comment: and how to highlight them? because i dont see how i can highlight all those expired dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using PHP 5.3 > , you can use [diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) to get the day difference between your date and +2 weeks and then decide if to apply the css class to the `<td>` or not.

Example:

```
// get two weeks from now
$date_in_two_weeks = strtotime('+2 weeks');
$date_in_two_weeks = date("Y/m/d",$date_in_two_weeks);

// get the date to compare, from db or whatever you want
$date_to_compare = "2014/02/01";

// compare the date in your list to now + 2 weeks and then put the date difference into $days_difference
$date_from_list = new DateTime($date_to_compare);
$date_in_two_weeks = new DateTime($date_in_two_weeks);
$days_difference = $date_from_list->diff($date_in_two_weeks);

if ($days_difference->days > 14) {
    $highlight_css_class = "highlight";
} else {
    $highlight_css_class = "";
}
```

Now in your table, apply css class to the `<td>` or wherever you want it.

```
<tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>hamburger</td>
    <td class="<?php echo $highlight_css_class;?>">2014-02-10</td>
</tr>
```

Of course in CSS create the `.highlight` class with the styling you want.

```
.highlight { 
    background:#e1e1e1;
}
```

Comment: this is what i needed. Going to check if i can get it to work. thx

Comment: it is not working, all the dates get highlighted, every class is "highlight"

Comment: Of course everything will be highlighted , you are comparing the same date... i think you need to go over the basics again.

Comment: 2014-06-10 is the second date in the table = it gets colored red with ur code