# error in highlight table dates

Tags: javascript, php, css

What is wrong with this code? I want to highlight all days from now + 2 weeks. But they all get highlighted with the .highlight class. Where is the error?

```
<?php 
// get two weeks from now
$date_in_two_weeks = strtotime('+2 weeks');
$date_in_two_weeks = date("Y-m-d",$date_in_two_weeks);

// get the date to compare, from db or whatever you want
$date_to_compare = "2014-02-01";

// compare the date in your list to now + 2 weeks and then put the date difference into $days_difference
$date_from_list = new DateTime($date_to_compare);
$date_in_two_weeks = new DateTime($date_in_two_weeks);
$days_difference = $date_from_list->diff($date_in_two_weeks);

if ($days_difference->days > 14) {
    $highlight_css_class = "highlight";
} else {
    $highlight_css_class = "none";
}
?>
<style>
.highlight { 
    color:#cc0000;
}
.none { 
}
</style>
<fieldset>
<table class="tablesorter" id="my-table" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>REK</th>
                <th>BESCHRIJVING</th>
                <th>VERVALDATUM</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


<tr><td>A1</td><td>hamburger</td><td class="<?php echo $highlight_css_class;?>">2014-02-10</td></tr>

<tr><td>A1</td><td>tomato</td><td class="<?php echo $highlight_css_class;?>">2014-06-10</td></tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I tested the code and changed a lot but I cant get it to work....
Thx in advance for any help.

Comment: you aren't doing any comparison per date, your doing one comparison. create a function, and pass in the current date in to determine the highlight class or you can do this simply in jquery.

Comment: You allways compare "2014-02-01", the dates you want compare "2014-02-10" and "2014-06-10" never has been compared in your code.

Comment: i cannot find the error in what i wrote... can u give me a working example?

Comment: check without giving class, whether the code is working fine or not..may be problem with adding class.

Comment: One of by now __four__ duplicates of your own question [Highlight all dates from now untill 2 weeks later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599315/highlight-all-dates-from-now-untill-2-weeks-later) Please stop this __now__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

`$date_in_two_weeks = strtotime('+2 week');`

instead of

`$date_in_two_weeks = strtotime('+2 weeks');`

you have to wirte `week` instead of `weeks` for getting correct timestamp of next two week

Comment: will beacause the difference is greater than 14. try to change compare date to 2014-02-15