# Highlight dates in past and dates that will expire in next two weeks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I am struggling with some code for a while now and I'm not able to solve it. I have a table in pure html. This html file is send to me every day, and every day the dates in the html file are updates.

It has a table structure. A number from a shelf, a description and a date when the product expires:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>coca cola</td><td>2014-08-17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>bread</td><td>2014-02-13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>apple</td><td>2014-01-20</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>cookies</td><td>2014-04-03</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I have several pieces of code tested and if u want i can post it here, but i want to keep my question as clean as possible instead of over flooding my question with pieces of code.

Now what i want is:

1. that dates that are allready in the past get colored orange
2. Dates that will expire within 2 weeks get colored red
3. The rest off the dates gets no color

my best try untill now is this piece of code:

```
<?php 

$date_to_compare = "2014/02/02";
$dateNow = new DateTime("now");
$dateCompare = new DateTime($date_to_compare);
$difference = $dateNow->diff($dateCompare);

//for debugging; %R gives you prefix (- or +); %a gives you days.
echo "Days in difference (from today until compare date): " . $difference->format('%R%a') . "<br />";

if ($difference->format('%R%a') < 0) {
    $highlight_css_class = "orange"; 
} elseif ($difference->format('%R%a') <= 14) {
    $highlight_css_class = "red";
} else {
    $highlight_css_class = "";
}
    ?>
```

and in my table I add a `td` class

```
<td class="<?php echo $highlight_css_class; ?>">...</td>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .red { 
        color : #f00; 
    }
    .orange { 
        color : #ffa500; 
    }
</style>
```

but this doesn't work... all dates get class red and get colored.... can someone help me. I am trying to fix this for 4 days now.

Comment: One of by now __four__ duplicates of your own question [Highlight all dates from now untill 2 weeks later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599315/highlight-all-dates-from-now-untill-2-weeks-later) Please stop this __now__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JS will pick out every 3rd child from within your tr tags, split the dates by their dashes into an array, use the array as a date, figure out the difference in time between that date and now in days, then apply your color styles.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wboco/dp4j4/)

> ```
> var parents = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
>
> for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
>     var parent = parents[i],
>         children = parent.children
>
> for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
>     var elem = children[j]
>     if (j % 3 === 2) {
>         var dateElement = elem.innerHTML;
>         var dateArray = dateElement.split("-");
>         var prevTime = new Date(dateArray);
>         var thisTime = new Date();
>         var diff = prevTime.getTime() - thisTime.getTime();
>         var days = 1000*60*60*24;
>         var diffInDays = Math.ceil(diff / days);
>         if (diffInDays < 0) {
>             elem.style.color = "#ffa500";
>         }
>         else if (diffInDays <= 14) {
>             elem.style.color = "#ff0000";
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: oh my thx finally someone who helped me. Works like a charm :)

Comment: @user3090697 Please delete your duplicates of this question to consolidate anyone else looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :) please hit like i need points. thanks :)

```
$date_to_compare = "2014/02/08";
$dateNow = new DateTime("now");
$dateCompare = new DateTime($date_to_compare);
$difference = $dateNow->diff($dateCompare);

$highlight_css_class = '';

if ($difference->invert) 
    $highlight_css_class = 'orange';
elseif ($difference->days <= 14) 
    $highlight_css_class = 'red';
}
echo $highlight_css_class;
?>
```